# How does iterator work with constructor

Tags: java, object, iterator

Hi I'm new to Java and I just encountered the following problem in a homework. I'm required to write a class that adds a new object to list when a void method is called. As a hint, the structure of an iterator method is given, so the core structure of my code now looks like this:

```
public class objectList implements Iterable<Obj> {

  private ArrayList<Obj> objectList;
  attribute_a A;
  attribute_b B;
  attribute_c C;


  public objectList(attribute_a A, attribute_b B, attribute_c C){
      objectList = new ArrayList<Obj>;
      this.A = A;
      this.B = B;
      this.C = C;
  }

  public void extendList(attribute_a A, attribute_b B, attribute_c C){
      objectList.add(new Obj(A,B,C));
  }

  public Iterator<Obj> iterator(){
      return objectList.iterator();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
      newstr = "";
      for(i = 0;i<objectList.size();i++)
      {
        //Assuming Obj has the method toString()
        //It prints out all details of each object, then join into one string
        newstr += objectList.get(i).toString();
      }
      return newstr;
  }
}
```

I'm told to just use java.util.iterator, not a custom iterator - so it saved me from defining HasNext(), next(), remove(), etc.

Edit: my goal is to be able to print objects stored in objectList, after extendList() is called several times i.e. there are many items stored in the list. Now I can only print the latest item in it (only 1 item is in the list).

What do I have to do to make the "cursor" automatically point to next item -> get attribute -> perform tasks on the attribute -> next item, etc. until the list is finished?

Comment: Are you saying you can able to print only the last Object and not all the Objects added?Is this your problem?

Comment: What's your toString output?

Comment: Kindly give your goal or definition of your problem statement (What do you want to achive ?)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what's going on here...

So, you have a class, and it has a field called `objectList`.  When you create a `new objectList` instance, the constructor gets called and the field is initialised to an empty list.  So far so good.  (However, why do you have the fields called `A`, `B` and `C`?  They don't seem to be used at all, so it seems confusing to require someone to pass three parameters to your constructor that are effectively ignored.)

Then, whenever `extendList` is called, a new `Obj` is added to the instance's list.  That looks about right.  This means that at any given point, we can say that the size of the `objectList` is equal to the number of times that `extendList` has been called on that object.

Equally, calling `iterator` will just return the standard Java iterator for this list.  So that iterator should visit every `Obj` in that list, which will be a number of items equal to the number of times that `extendList` was called on the same `objectList` object.

**So - why doesn't it work**?

It's not clear from the code you've posted.  Your class itself looks OK, so the conclusion is that you must be calling it wrong.  My *guess* is that you're actually constructing multiple instances of the class - every time you call the constructor, you create a new instance with different fields.  For example, this won't do what you expect:

```
new objectList().extendList("A1", "B1", "C1");
new objectList().extendList("A2", "B2", "C2");
new objectList().extendList("A3", "B3", "C3");
return new objectList().iterator();
```

because a new instance is created each time, effectively throwing the state away from before.  You'd want to rewrite that as:

```
objectList ol = new objectList();
ol.extendList("A1", "B1", "C1");
ol.extendList("A2", "B2", "C2");
ol.extendList("A3", "B3", "C3");
return ol.iterator();
```

If that doesn't solve it, look at how you're using the class, count how many times you call `extendList` on the same instance that you get the iterator from.  If in doubt - get Java to count for you - add `System.out.println("in extendList")` calls (and perhaps some in the constructor) to see what gets called when.  In fact, if there's a concern that different instances of the class are being used, you can get a unique identifier for the specific instance with `System.identityHashcode()`, e.g.:

```
 public void extendList(attribute_a A, attribute_b B, attribute_c C){
    System.out.println("Extending list for " + System.identityHashcode() + " with " + A + ", " + B + ", " + C);
    objectList.add(new Obj(A,B,C));
 }
```

Failing that, it may be worth getting familiar with how to use a debugger, and stepping through your program line by line.  This will let you see the state of your program at every step, and hopefully it'll make it clear to you where things start diverging from your expectations.

---

(I'll also encourage you to use standard Java naming conventions, as your code is surprisingly challenging to read at the moment without them.  Class names should start with capitals (and be in UpperCamelCase).  Variables and field names should start with lower case letters (and be in lowerCamelCase).  At the moment your class name looks like a variable, and your fields look like generic parameters.  `new objectList()` just looks wrong!)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! The methods are called by a given test file, in which it goes: ol.extendList("A","B","C") twice and tries to match the outcome of toString() with an expected string. I'm just going to read more on standard conventions and constructors now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing this `objectList = new ArrayList<Obj>;` out side the constructor,

```
private ArrayList<Obj> objectList=new ArrayList<Obj>();
```

Comment: Besides the fact that it's not very clear what problem the OP has, there is technically no real difference between initializing the list field at declaration point or as a first statement in the constructor. I agree that it is better, though. But this answer will in no way help the OP with his (still to be better explained) problem.